# Regular Expression to evaluate and replace arithmetic operators operators

Tags: java, regex

i need a regular expression that would replace arithmetic operators in a given string. I need to be able to replace the operators with "|".

for instance,

```
String input = "5.0+9.0-(-2.0)";

String replace = input.replaceAll("[+-//*&&[^.]&&[^(-]]", "|");
```

in this instance i intend only to replace the operators outside the brackets. I think the regular expression has to be modified more to read only the "-" outside the brackets but i'm ought of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace (and not evaluate) the arithmetic operators which are not in parenthesis you can try:

```
String replace = input.replaceAll("[-+*/](?![^(]*\\))","|");
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/uILyQ)

Answer (score 0):

This seems difficult to do with one regular expression.
I think the best way is to extract the bracketed expressions and replace the arithmetic operations in the remaining string. Because regex can't cope with brackets.

For help with the extraction [Regular expression to detect semi-colon terminated C++ for & while loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624) may help you.