# extracts the number of (outer) items inside the parentheses

Tags: python, regex, string, algorithm

I want to extract the number of (outer) items inside the parentheses associated with `a`.
For example for the following examples:

```
a(b(c d) f)
```

`a` has two items `b(c d)` and `f` therefore output is 2.

```
e(a(h f))
```

`a` has two items `h` and `f` therefore output is 2.

```
b(c a(d(f) h(i j) l(2 k z)))
```

`a` has three items `d(f)` and `h(i j)` and `l(2 k z)` therefore output is 3.

Not sure how solve this but first I try to convert the strings to where they start with `a(`

```
m=re.search("a\((.*)\)\)", string)
print m.group()
```

What's the best approach to solve this?

Comment: Parentheses matching cannot be done with regexp.

Comment: "What's the best approach to solve this?" Use something other than a regular expression. In particular, this requires a so-called "push down automata". You can implement this by parsing the string manually, one character at a time.

Comment: This can be done so much more easily with a loop and (open) parenthesis counter

Comment: You can use a simple loop with several condition which will increment the counter

Comment: I was about to answer with a simple implementation of a parentheses aprser, but the question got closed, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50702934/5079316)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class with recursion to build a structure with nested lists to represent each item and its contents in parenthesis:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import re
class Token(NamedTuple):
   value:str
   type:str

class Parse:
  grammer = r'\w+|\)|\('
  types = [('alpha', '\w+'), ('Oparen', '\('), ('Cparen', '\)')]
  def __init__(self, parsed):
     self.parsed = iter(parsed)
     self.stack = []
     self.parse()
  def parse(self):
    start = next(self.parsed, None)
    if start and start.type != 'Cparen':
      if start.type == 'alpha':
         self.stack.append(start.value)
      elif start.type == 'Oparen':
         _p = Parse(self.parsed)
         self.parsed = _p.parsed
         self.stack.append(_p.stack)
      self.parse()
  def __len__(self):
     return sum(isinstance(i, str) for i in self.stack[-1])
  def __getitem__(self, func):
     return self.__class__.find_length(func, self.stack)
  @classmethod
  def find_length(cls, val, params):
     for i in range(len(params)-1):
        if params[i] == val:
          return sum(not isinstance(i, list) for i in params[i+1])
        if isinstance(params[i+1], list):
          return cls.find_length(val, params[i+1])
  @staticmethod
  def tokenize(d):
    return [Token(i, [a for a, b in Parse.types if re.findall(b, i)][0]) for i in re.findall(Parse.grammer, d)]
```

---

```
s = ['a(b(c d) f)', 'e(a(h f))', 'b(c a(d(f) h(i j) l(2 k z)))']
c = list(map(lambda x:Parse(Parse.tokenize(x)), s))
print([i['a'] for i in c])
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 3]
```