# python parse text in nested parentheses for n-ary tree

Tags: python, parsing, nested

I have text like that :

```
Proxy='ab,cd(ef,gh),ij,kl(mn(op,kr),st),uv'
```

The expected result would be a nested list in order to create a nary tree representation of the text, so:

```
ExpectedResult=['ab','cd',['ef','gh'],'ij','kl',['mn',['op','kr'],'st'],'uv']
```

My try:

```
temp=[]
stack=[]
comma=[]
op=[]
cl=[]
n=(len(test))

for idx in range(n):
    if test[idx] == ',' and not op and not cl and not comma:
        stack.append(test[0:idx])
        comma.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == ',' and op and not cl and not comma:
        temp.append(test[op.pop()+1:idx])
        comma.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == ',' and not op and cl and not comma:
        if len(test[cl[0]+1:idx]) > 1:
            stack.append(test[cl.pop()+1:idx])
            comma.append(idx)
        else:
            cl.pop()
            comma.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == ',' and not op and not cl and comma:
        stack.append(test[comma.pop():idx])
        comma.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == '(' and not op and not cl and comma:
        stack.append(test[comma.pop()+1:idx])
        op.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == '(' and op and not cl and comma:
        temp.append(test[comma.pop()+1:idx])
        op.pop()
        op.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == ')' and not op and not cl and comma:
        temp.append(test[comma.pop()+1:idx])
        stack.append(temp)
        temp=[]
        cl.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == ')' and op and not cl and not comma:
        temp.append([test[op.pop()+1:idx]])
        cl.append(idx)
    elif test[idx] == ')' and not op and not cl and comma:
        temp.append(test[comma.pop()+1:idx])
        stack.append(temp)
        temp=[]
        cl.append(idx)
```

I have found very interesting things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284991/parsing-nested-parentheses-in-python-grab-content-by-level)

But this method will return a list of char and I want to join words (not 'a','b' but 'ab') and most of all I do not understand the syntax (and so the function) of the push function.

Comment: Ok, So i dig up this post for a solution i have found using ast. The aime is to modify the string given in input in order to look like a list and then to evaluate it with ast (ast.literal_eval(chain)). here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

As iit is said in the comment, here my solution that can be adapted to any sort of string. The trick is to transform the string given in input to look like a list and then use ast to effectively transform it into a list.

```
def parenthesesParser(string):
    ref=[]
    string=re.sub('\.','',string)
    string=string.rstrip(', ')
    for char in string:
        if char == '(':
            ref.append('\',[\'')
        elif char == ')':
            ref.append('\']')
        elif char == ',':
            ref.append('\',\'')
        elif char == '.':
            ref.append('\',\'')
        else:
            ref.append(char)
    ref='\''+''.join(ref)+'\''
    ref=re.sub('\'\'','\'',ref)
    ref=re.sub(']\'',']',ref)
   return ast.literal_eval(ref.strip())
```