# Handle nested fields with conversion types in string with string.Formatter

Tags: python, string, nested, string-formatting, formatter

### Update 2

Alright, my answer to this question is *not* a complete solution to what I originally wanted but it's ok for simpler things like filename templating (what I originally intended to use this for). I have yet to come up with a solution for recursive templating. It might not matter to me though as I have reevaluated what I really need. Though it's possible I'll need bigger guns in the future, but then I'll probably just [choose another more advanced templating engine instead of reinventing the tire.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)

### Update

Ok I realize now string.Template probably is the better way to do this. I'll answer my own question when I have a working example.

---

I want to accomplish formatting strings by grouping keys and arbitrary text together in a nesting manner, like so

```py
# conversions (!):
# u = upper case
# l = lower case
# c = capital case
# t = title case

fmt = RecursiveNamespaceFormatter(globals())

greeting = 'hello'
person = 'foreName surName'
world = 'WORLD'

sample = 'WELL {greeting!u} {super {person!t}, {tHiS iS tHe {world!t}!l}!c}!'

print(fmt.format(sample))

# output: WELL HELLO Super Forename Surname, this is the World!
```

I've subclassed string.Formatter to populate the nested fields which I retrieve with regex, and it works fine, except for the fields with a conversion type which doesn't get converted.

```py
import re
from string import Formatter

class RecursiveNamespaceFormatter(Formatter):
   def __init__(self, namespace={}):
       Formatter.__init__(self)
       self.namespace = namespace

   def vformat(self, format_string, *args, **kwargs):
       def func(i):
           i = i.group().strip('{}')
           return self.get_value(i,(),{})
       format_string = re.sub('\{(?:[^}{]*)\}', func, format_string)
       try:
           return super().vformat(format_string, args, kwargs)
       except ValueError:
           return self.vformat(format_string)

   def get_value(self, key, args, kwds):
       if isinstance(key, str):
           try:
               # Check explicitly passed arguments first
               return kwds[key]
           except KeyError:
               return self.namespace.get(key, key) # return key if not found (e.g. key == "this is the World")
       else:
           super().get_value(key, args, kwds)

   def convert_field(self, value, conversion):
       if conversion == "u":
           return str(value).upper()
       elif conversion == "l":
           return str(value).lower()
       elif conversion == "c":
           return str(value).capitalize()
       elif conversion == "t":
           return str(value).title()
       # Do the default conversion or raise error if no matching conversion found
       return super().convert_field(value, conversion)
```

```py
# output: WELL hello!u super foreName surName!t, tHiS iS tHe WORLD!t!l!c!
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You mean like `this {is a \{string!c\}!u}`? I guess i could to that but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a complicated thing with this, especially with the limitations of python's `re` module. Before I tackled on with `string.Template`, I experimented with [looping through the string and stacking all relevant indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285211), to order each nested field in hierarchy. Maybe a combination of the two could work, I'm not sure.

Here's however a working, *non-recursive* example:

```py
from string import Template, _sentinel_dict

class MyTemplate(Template):
    delimiter = '$'
    pattern = '\$(?:(?P<escaped>\$)|\{(?P<braced>[\w]+)(?:\.(?P<braced_func>\w+)\(\))*\}|(?P<named>(?:[\w]+))(?:\.(?P<named_func>\w+)\(\))*|(?P<invalid>))'

    def substitute(self, mapping=_sentinel_dict, **kws):
        if mapping is _sentinel_dict:
            mapping = kws
        elif kws:
            mapping = _ChainMap(kws, mapping)

        def convert(mo):

            named = mapping.get(mo.group('named'), mapping.get(mo.group('braced')))
            func = mo.group('named_func') or mo.group('braced_func') # i.e. $var.func() or ${var.func()}

            if named is not None:

                if func is not None:
                    # if named doesn't contain func, convert it to str and try again.
                    callable_named = getattr(named, func, getattr(str(named), func, None))
                    if callable_named:
                        return str(callable_named())
                return str(named)

            if mo.group('escaped') is not None:
                return self.delimiter
            if mo.group('invalid') is not None:
                self._invalid(mo)
            if named is not None:
                raise ValueError('Unrecognized named group in pattern',
                                 self.pattern)

        return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
```

```py
sample1 = 'WELL $greeting.upper() super$person.title(), tHiS iS tHe $world.title().lower().capitalize()!'
S = MyTemplate(sample1)
print(S.substitute(**{'greeting': 'hello', 'person': 'foreName surName', 'world': 'world'}))

# output: WELL HELLO super Forename Surname, tHiS iS tHe World!

sample2 = 'testing${äää.capitalize()}.upper()ing $NOT_DECLARED.upper() $greeting '
sample2 += '$NOT_DECLARED_EITHER ASDF$world.upper().lower()ASDF'
S = MyTemplate(sample2)
print(S.substitute(**{
        'some_var': 'some_value',
        'äää': 'TEST',
        'greeting': 'talofa',
        'person': 'foreName surName',
        'world': 'världen'
}))

# output: testingTest.upper()ing  talofa  ASDFvärldenASDF

sample3 = 'a=$a.upper() b=$b.bit_length() c=$c.bit_length() d=$d.upper()'
S = MyTemplate(sample3)
print(S.substitute(**{'a':1, 'b':'two', 'c': 3, 'd': 'four'}))

# output: a=1 b=two c=2 d=FOUR
```

As you can see, `$var` and `${var}` works as expected, but the fields can also handle type methods. If the method is not found, it converts the value to `str` and checks again.

The methods can't take any arguments though. It also only catches the last method so chaining doesn't work either, which I believe is because `re` do not allow multiple groups to use the same name ([the regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) does however).

With some tweaking of the regex pattern and some extra logic in `convert` both these things should be easily fixed.

`MyTemplate.substitute` works like `MyTemplate.safe_substitute` by not throwing exceptions on missing keys or fields.