# Regex: Match brackets both greedy and non greedy

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I'm using python regular expression module, `re` .

I need to match anything inside '(' ')' on this two phrases, but "not so greedy". Like this:

```
show the (name) of the (person)

calc the sqrt of (+ (* (2 4) 3))
```

The result should return, from phrase 1:

```
name
person
```

The result should return from phrase 2:

```
+ (* (2 4) 3)
```

The problem is that, to fit first phrase, I used `'\(.*?\)'`

This, on second phrase, just fits `+ (* (2 4)`

And using `'\(.*\)'` to fit second phrase correctly, on first phrase fits `(name) of the (person)`

What regex work on both phrases correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: A very good Python+PyQT3-based tool to test regexps is Kodos. Check it out, it helps me a lot when I'm in "regexp doubt".

Comment: To elaborate on @Chris' comment, it looks like you're trying to use regular expressions to parse a language which isn't regular. Don't do that.

Comment: Another very similar question about nested brackets in python is here [stackoverflow.com/questions/524548](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pyparsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/) makes it easy to write simple one-off parsers for stuff like this:

```
>>> text = """show the (name) of the (person)
...
... calc the sqrt of (+ (* (2 4) 3))"""
>>> import pyparsing
>>> for match in pyparsing.nestedExpr('(',')').searchString(text):
...   print match[0]
...
['name']
['person']
['+', ['*', ['2', '4'], '3']]
```

Note that the nesting parens have been discarded, and the nested text returned as a nested structure.

If you want the original text for each parenthetical bit, then use the originalTextFor modifier:

```
>>> for match in pyparsing.originalTextFor(pyparsing.nestedExpr('(',')')).searchString(text):
...   print match[0]
...
(name)
(person)
(+ (* (2 4) 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do looks like a shunting yard (actually it looks like LISP, so maybe you should check [PyLisp](http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~annis/creations/PyLisp/) out). There is no need to use regexps to parse these kind of expressions.

See [Shunting yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) article @ wikipedia and it's Python [implementation](http://en.literateprograms.org/Shunting_yard_algorithm_%28Python%29).

Answer (score 0):

This matches all of the required info:

```
(?:\()(.*?\){2})|(?:\()(.*?)(?:\))
```

Group 1 = **+ (* (2 4) 3)**

- The last ")" can be stripped off with .strip(')')

Group 2 = **name**, **person**

Answer (score -3):

As long as the brackets are not nested, you can use a lazy regex:

```
\(.*?\)
```

While you can theoretically parse a limited amount of nesting in a regex, it's very hard and not worth the effort.  It's much easier to do that using a custom python function.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns/133684#133684) for a good explanation.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the 2nd example that sometimes the parentheses _are_ nested.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Yeah, I just thought the OP might be interested in the syntax for non-greedy matching