# RegEx Starts with [ and ending with ] - match words only

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following strin:

```
var s = "my [first] ga[m]e and [abc]de]\nThe [Game]"
```

Which regex do I use to match:

```
0 - [first]
1 - [abc]de]
2 - [Game]
```

I have tried `var pattern2 = new Regex(@"\W\[.*?\]\W");` but it doesn't find `[Game]`

I also want to be able to match "`[my] gamers\t[pro]`"

```
0 - [my]
1 - [pro]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets with further reading at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that. He's not looking for balanced brackets (`[abc]de]` is not balanced), he's looking for brackets that are at word boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\[[^\[]{2,}\]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[         # Match a [
[^\[]{2,}  # Match two or more non-[ characters
\]         # Match ]
```

See it on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?32ekh).

Comment: Good but I still had to think about it despite the explanation. :)

Comment: I don't think this is working. I changed the input to `my [first] ga[m]e and ]de]\nThe [Game]` and it matched `[m]e and ]de]`.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, the regex allows any characters except `[` between the two delimiting brackets. The specs aren't very clear on what is and what isn't allowed in a "word". Perhaps `\[\S{2,}\]` would be a better fit (allowing only non-space characters between the brackets) - but that remains for the OP to specify.

Comment: I'd just put both left and right brackets in the negative class like so: `\[[^[\]]{2,}\]`. +1.

Comment: @ridgerunner: That won't work because some of the examples contain a closing bracket as part of the word to be matched...

Answer (score 0):

You need to match beginning and end of the string explicitly, in addition to non-word characters:

```
(?:^|\W)\[(.*?)\](?:$|\W)
```

The capture group will get the words inside the brackets.