# JavaScript regexp repeating (sub)group

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to return all the repeating and matching subgroups from a single call with a regular expression?

For example, I have a string like :

```
{{token id=foo1 class=foo2 attr1=foo3}}
```

Where the number of attributes (i.e. `id`, `class`, `attr1`) are undefined and could be any `key=value` pair.

For example, at the moement, I have the following [regexp and output](http://regex101.com/r/tP3hF1)

```
var pattern = /\{{([\w\.]+)(?:\s+(\w+)=(?:("(?:[^"]*)")|([\w\.]+)))*\}\}/;
var str = '{{token arg=1 id=2 class=3}}';

var matches = str.match(pattern);
// -> ["{{token arg=1 id=2 class=3}}", "token", "class", undefined, "3"]
```

It seems that it only matches the last group; Is there any way to get all the other "attributes" (`arg` and `id`)?

**Note**: the example illustrate match on a single string, but the searched pattern be be located in a much larger string, possibly containing many matches. So, `^` and `$` cannot be used.

Comment: so you want both the key and value in a single regex?

Comment: provide some test cases and what the output should be

Comment: yes, I want all of them returned. I thought I could have sub-groups. Perhaps a sub-array of matches, or something.

Comment: @AmitJoki, There's already a test case, whatever the expected output, I want the regexp to match and return (perhaps in sub-groups) **all** the "attributes", and not only the last one.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but I think you have one more grouping than you need. Seems like this `"(?:[^"]*)"` could just be this  `"[^"]*"`

Comment: So you want the result to be something like this, right? `["{{token arg=1 id=2 class=3}}", "token", "arg", undefined, "1", "id", undefined, "2" "class", undefined, "3"]`

Comment: Well anyway, I'm not a regex pro, but I'm pretty sure you're going to be doing this in two passes. One to get each `{{...}}` group *(which can have subgroups of the 'token' and all the 'attributes')*, then another pass to break down the attributes for each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to do in one regular expression.  JavaScript Regex will only return to you the last matched group which is exactly your problem.  I had this seem issue a while back: [Regex only capturing last instance of capture group in match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393683/regex-only-capturing-last-instance-of-capture-group-in-match).  You can get this to work in .Net, but that's probably not what you need.

I'm sure you can figure out how to do this in a regular expressions, and the spit the arguments from the second group.

```
\{\{(\w+)\s+(.*?)\}\}
```

Here's some javaScript code to show you how it's done:

```
var input = $('#input').text();
var regex = /\{\{(\w+)\s*(.*?)\}\}/g;
var match;
var attribs;
var kvp;
var output = '';

while ((match = regex.exec(input)) != null) {
    output += match[1] += ': <br/>';

    if (match.length > 2) {
        attribs = match[2].split(/\s+/g);
        for (var i = 0; i < attribs.length; i++) {
            kvp = attribs[i].split(/\s*=\s*/);
            output += ' - ' + kvp[0] + ' = ' + kvp[1] + '<br/>';       
        }
    }
}
$('#output').html(output);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVsh8/)

A crazy idea would be to use a regex and replace to convert your code into json and then decode with JSON.parse.  I know the following is a start to that idea.

```
/[\s\S]*?(?:\{\{(\w+)\s+(.*?)\}\}|$)/g.replace(input, doReplace);

function doReplace ($1, $2, $3) {
  if ($2) {
    return "'" + $2 + "': {" + 
      $3.replace(/\s+/g, ',')
        .replace(/=/g, ':')
        .replace(/(\w+)(?=:)/g, "'$1'") + '};\n';       
    }
   return '';
 }
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/hva6qv)

Comment: Yes, I remember doing this in .Net at some point, maybe why I got confused about subgroups and all (.Net has corrupted my JavaScript!). I'll just match the entire `key=value` attribute list, then, and parse them separately in that case.

Comment: Yes, this is a clever idea (the second one). With a little modifications, it is possible to generate a JSON string that can be parsed. :) Note, however that I've decided to drop using regexp in favor of a state machine parser; more flexibility and error management. But you totally suggested an innovative approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var s = "{{token id=foo1 class=foo2 attr1=foo3 hi=we}} hiwe=wef";
var matches = s.match(/(\w+(?==\w+)|(?!==\w+)\w+)(?!\{\{)(?!.*token)(?=.*}})/g);
matches.splice(0,1);
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    alert(matches[i]);
}
```

The regex is `/(\w+(?==\w+)|(?!==\w+)\w+)(?!\{\{)(?!.*token)(?=.*}})/g` (Use global modifier `g` to match all attributes)

The array will look like this:

```
["id","foo1","class","foo2","attr1","foo3","hi","we"]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HYW72/1/

Comment: That's far too loose. It'll include matches outside the `{{}}` and makes no check for `token`.

Comment: Still matches stuff outside the `}}` http://jsfiddle.net/cmjwy/3/ And you're not capturing the values that OP wants.

Comment: @cookiemonster, see OP's commment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511031/javascript-regexp-repeating-subgroup/22511524#comment-34251012

Comment: Yes, I saw that comment. You're only capturing the attribute name, not the value as well, nor the starting token *(which presumably isn't literally the word "token")* as shown in the question.

Comment: I really don't think you're understanding what he wants. This is presumably for some sort of templating system, and he needs every grouping of `{{word attr=val attr2=val2}}`, where there could be multiple groupings in a large string, and the values of the attributes may or may not be quoted. http://jsfiddle.net/cmjwy/5/

Comment: Sorry, but no. It picks up matches outside the `{{}}` boundaries. http://jsfiddle.net/HYW72/2/

Comment: @AmitJoki, so, basically you're suggesting a two pass approach?

Comment: @YanickRochon, I'm coming up with a single regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "{{token id=foo1 class=foo2 attr1=foo3}}"
if lMatches = str.match(///^
        \{\{
        ([a-z][a-z0-9]*)   # identifier
        (
            (?:
                \s+
                ([a-z][a-z0-9]*)  # identifier
                =
                (\S*)             # value
                )*
            )
        \}\}
        $///)
    [_, token, attrStr] = lMatches

    hAttr = {}
    for lMatches from attrStr.matchAll(///
            ([a-z][a-z0-9]*)  # identifier
            =
            (\S*)             # value
            ///g)
        [_, key, value] = lMatches
        hAttr[key] = value

    console.log "token = '#{token}'"
    console.log hAttr
else
    console.log "NO MATCH"
```

This is CoffeeScript - because it's SO much easier to read. I hate it when .NET gets something right that JavaScript just fails on, but you have to match the entire string of attribute/value pairs in one regexp, then, you have to parse that to get what you want (matchAll(), which returns an iterator, is handy here). The /// style regexp runs until the next /// and makes whitespace not significant, which also allows comments. There are lots of assumptions here, like keys are identifiers, only lower-case letters, values are any run of non-whitespace, including empty, attribute names are unique, etc. but they're easily modified.

FYI, the above code outputs:

```
token = 'token'
{ id: 'foo1', class: 'foo2', attr1: 'foo3' }
```