# Why is my regex capture group only capturing the last part of the string when it matches multiple parts?

Tags: javascript, regex, quantifiers, capture-group

## What I Tried

```
var test = "asdfdas ABCD EFGH";
var regex = /^\S+( [A-Z]{4})+$/; 
    // Also tried: /^\S+( [A-Z]{4})+$/g
    // And: /^\S+( [A-Z]{4})+?$/g
var matches = test.match(regex);
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLupp7za/).

## What I Expect

The variable `matches` should become this array:

```
[
  "asdfdas ABCD EFGH",
  " ABCD",
  " EFGH"
]
```

## What I Get

The variable `matches` is actually this array:

```
[
  "asdfdas ABCD EFGH",
  " EFGH"
]
```

## My Thoughts

My guess is that there's something I'm missing with the capture group and/or `$` logic. Any help would be appreciated. (I know I can figure out how to do this in multiple regular expressions, but I want to understand what is happening here.)

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what it does; you’re not doing anything wrong. When a group is given a quantifier, it only captures its last match, and that’s all it will ever do in JavaScript. The general fix is to use multiple regular expressions, as you said.

Comment: That’s not a correct duplicate, @anubhava; there’s no `/g` flag.

Comment: Sorry you can link another Q&A with more answers but idea is same to call `re.exec()` in a `while` loop to get all the matches. Using `g` flag is indeed the correct way here to find multiple matches.

Comment: Get rid of `$`.  Right now you're only testing for `\w{4}` as it occurs at the end of the string.

Comment: The pattern backtracking happens twice. It is the expected behaviour.

Comment: AFAIK, only .NET's regex engine lets you extract all the captures for a given group (it actually has a capture stack). But in JS, you have to do what anubhava said.

Comment: @minitech I'm going to edit my question to be more informative. Write up the answer, and you'll get yourself a green check. :)

Comment: hope this will be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393683/regex-only-capturing-last-instance-of-capture-group-in-match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that’s exactly what it does; you’re not doing anything wrong. When a group is given a quantifier, it only captures its last match, and that’s all it will ever do in JavaScript. The general fix is to use multiple regular expressions, as you said, e.g.

```
var test = "asdfdas ABCD EFGH";
var match = test.match(/^\S+((?: [A-Z]{4})+)$/); // capture all repetitions
var matches = match[1].match(/ [A-Z]{4}/g); // match again to get individual ones
```