# Regex first entry

Tags: javascript, regex

```
pattern = /domain\.com\/go\/(.*)3/i;

//alias always ends with "3"
url1 = "domain.com/go/firstname3";
url2 = "domain.com/go/secondname3?p=123";

console.log(url1.match(pattern)[1]); //firstname
console.log(url2.match(pattern)[1]); //secondname3?p=12
```

In both of examples I need return param without "3" ("firstname", "secondname").  It means I have to find first entry of char "3". First example works correctly

How should I change the pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\w*` instead of `.*`

```
pattern = /domain\.com\/go\/(\w*)3/i;
```

or

```
pattern = /domain\.com\/go\/(\w*)3\b/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because you are repeating the capturing group, and all language implementations preserve only the last capturing group. In other words, if there is a choice between capturing `secondname` and `secondname3?p=12`, Javascript will choose the last one even though both are equally valid. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393683/regex-only-capturing-last-instance-of-capture-group-in-match) explains the core of the problem.

The correct way to resolve such issues is to rewrite your regex group to make the parameter you want to retrieve unambiguous - usually this is done by changing occurrences of `.*` (note it is the `.` character here that is problematic) to something more appropriate, such as `\w*` in this case. You want to avoid repeating capturing groups. I will explain why `\w` does so.

Here `\w` represents the word metacharacter - it matches a-z, A-Z and 0-9 and nothing else. In this particular case, the regex can no longer match against `secondname3?p=12` because it contains an `=`, which isn't allowed by `\w`. Hence why @Avinash Raj's solution works - even though the capturing group is repeated, there is only one real instance of the whole thing matching.