# Matching a line protocol string with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string like this: `test0,id=28084 type=high,18765003 138456387`

And I'm using this regex:

```js
const str = `test0,id=28084 type=high,18765003 138456387`;

console.log(str.match(/\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+)\s*,\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+\s*)*\s*,\s*([0-9.]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s*/))
```

But I am not getting the `id` part. Just `type=high`.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I see that I will only get the last capture group. But not stated in the question, I need there to be a dynamic number of fields at that point in the string. I'm wondering if there's some other way to accomplish this.

Comment: If you repeat a capturing group with a * or + quantifier, you will get only the last match for that group. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393683

Comment: @horcrux Oh I see. Any idea how I could get the functionality I want with a regex?

Comment: Just repeat the same group manually (e.g. https://regex101.com/r/Olhe18/1).

Comment: @horcrux What if I need it to be N number of fields there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture in the same group all the key-value pairs and then split them:

```js
const str = `test0,id=28084 type=high,18765003 138456387`;
matches = str.match(/\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+)\s*,\s*((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+\s*)*)\s*,\s*([0-9.]+)\s*([0-9]+)\s*/)
matches.splice.apply(matches, [2, 1].concat(matches[2].split(/\s+/)));
console.log(matches)
```

Notice that I changed in your regex the second group from `(...)*` to `((?:...)*)`.