# Remove echo content with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a java program that parses some shell code and I want to remove the content inside echo statements. For the beginning, I want to take the whole echo command. My actual pattern looks like this:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("echo[\\t ]+\".*?\"");
```

This will match echo + at least one space or tab + double quotes + the smallest number of characters (I used the reluctant quantifier) + double quotes.

The problem is when I have an echo like this:

```
echo "This will not \" work";
```

My pattern will match only until backslash. 
What could I do fix this?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043454/using-regexes-how-to-efficiently-match-strings-between-double-quotes-with-embed); but be aware that this is far from being the only way to quote arguments in a shell line.

Comment: How else could you do it?

Comment: FOr instance: `echo This\ wi'l'"l no"t' "'\ wor'k'` <-- this will produce the exact same result as the quoted command in your example

Answer (score 2):

You can use **negative look-behind** to ensure that the last character isn't a `\`:

```
"echo[\\t ]+\".*?(?<!\\\\)\""
```

`\\\\` represents a single `\` character. It needs to be escaped to `\\` for the regex and then each `\` needs to be escaped again for the compiler.

[Test](https://ideone.com/TWBgDh).

[More about look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

A problem with the above is that `echo "\\"` will not match (presumably `\` is an escape character and `\\` means the `\` character). A more correct method might be to check for `\`'s, and **consume the character following each `\`**:

```
"echo[\\t ]+\"(\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?\""
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/FFQDgb).

Comment: That is a rather complicated solution compared to loop unrolling :p

Comment: @fge `\"(\\\\.|.)*?\"` VS `\"[^\\\\\"]*(\\\\.[^\\\\\"]*)*\"`? I'm more inclined to say that the prior is simpler.

Comment: Not me. Being short is one thing, being understandable is another ;) What is more, your regex will match `"""`

Comment: @fge If given `echo """` it will find `echo ""`, which, from the question, as stated, appears to be correct. I interpreted the question as being a `find`, not a `matches`.

Comment: Except this is not valid in the shell, and I very much doubt OP wants that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alternation that will match `\"` specifically

```
echo[\\t ]+\"([^\\\\]|\\\\\")*?\"
```