# Fetching strings from a .java file using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I working on making a Regex pattern where I can extract strings starting with ' " ' and ending with ' " '. But here is the problem - a String may also contains a ' " ' with escape character like this ' \" '. Just like this one `"This is a \"Demo\" text"`. Now I know very little about lookbehind operator. I just need some suggestion if this is possible with a single Regex Pattern ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Java to parse Java ? If not, what regex engine are you using ? Here's a start [`(?<!\\)"(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?"`](http://regex101.com/r/vM2dL8). Also what have you tried ?

Comment: You should have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043454/using-regexes-how-to-efficiently-match-strings-between-double-quotes-with-embed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
"(?:\\.|[^"])+"
```

without lookahead/behind stuff.
This does the following:

1. Look for a `"`, consume it
2. Check if the next 2 characters are a backslash followed by any character (this will match two backslashes `\\`, where the first is masking the second, and `\"` as well). If that can not be found, go to Step 3. If found, consume those 2 characters and repeat Step 2.
3. Check if the next character is not a `"`. If so, consume and go to step 2. If not (it IS a `"`), go to Step 4
4. Consume the `"` which must be here

As HamZa pointed out, this Regex will fail if a `"` is found outside of a string and not intended to be a start of a string. E.g. for Java Code this is the case if you have something like

```
Character c = '\"'
```

(" as a char) or

```
if (foo) { /* chosen "sometimes */ String g = "bar"; }
```

(random " inside a comment)

Comment: Aww. Too late. Could someone explain to me if lookbehind (like in HamZa's comment) is necessary here or if my solution works, too?

Comment: This would fail for `"This a \\\\" this shouldn't be matched \"`. Ok, it's an edge case, I know :)

Comment: I just fixed that issue since it came to my mind just as i posted it ;)

Comment: @TheM You need the lookbehind since it will fail for `do \" not match this but "match this"`. Anyways, +1

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand why that's needed, I thought of the text to be java (or some other) code, which wouldn't allow a `\"` to occur somewhere outside a string (except for `'\"'` of course, but that's a real edge case ;) )
Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @TheM This pattern is working like charm. Would you please explain me briefly how is it working ?