# Regex match for string literal including escape sequence

Tags: java, regex

This works just fine for normal string literal ("hello").

```
"([^"]*)"
```

But I also want my regex to match literal such as "hell\"o".
This what i have been able to come up with but it doesn't work.

```
("(?=(\\")*)[^"]*")
```

here I have tried to look ahead for <\">.

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043454/using-regexes-how-to-efficiently-match-strings-between-double-quotes-with-embed). It allows you to do what you want and even more.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Pattern.compile("\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*)\"")// 
                         ^^ - to match " literal
                     ^^^^   - to match \ literal
                     ^^^^^^ - will match \" literal
```

or

```
Pattern.compile("\"((?:\\\\\"|[^\"])*)\"")//
```

if you don't want to add more capturing groups.

This regex accept `\"` or any non `"` between quotation marks.

---

Demo:

```
    String input = "ab \"cd\" ef \"gh \\\"ij\"";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"((?:\\\\\"|[^\"])*)\"").matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Output:

```
cd
gh \"ij
```

Comment: Will work, however will "fail slow". See the link I posted above which is "fail fast" ;)

Comment: @fge Idea you are describing is very nice, but I had problems with creating regex which will also match `"ab\c\"d"` where as you can see ``\`` is placed not only before `"`, but also before other characters.

Comment: Simple modification: just replace `special` with `\\.` ;)

Comment: I thought about it earlier. In most cases this is good solution, because even numbers of ``\`` shouldn't be treated as escape sequence, so in case of `"ab\\"c"` correct match would be ``ab\\``). But if OP for some reasons doesn't want this "functionality" simple regex as I posted will do their job.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
"((?:[^"\\\\]*|\\\\.)*)"
```

`[^"\\\\]*` now will not match `\` anymore either. But on the other alternation, you get to match any escaped character.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:\\\"|[^\"])*)");
```

`\\\"` to match `\"` or,

`[^\"]` to match anything by `"`