# Matching pattern enclosed in quotes

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get groups which match the pattern.
Input String is class equals

```
'one and two!' and 'three or four five' and 'six'
```

I have tried following pattern. But it matches and which is not within single quotes

`(?:'(?:\S*\s*)*(and|or)+(?:\s*\S*)*')+`

I want groups like

```
'one and two!'
'three or four five'
```

All String which has and|or within single quotes should be matched. within single quote it can have special characters and many spaces etc

How can i alter the pattern which i have above?

Comment: Can you also have embedded single quotes?

Comment: Embedded single quotes? You mean something like this 'one and 'two''? Yes it can have any special character. like 'one and two's' is possible

Comment: And they won't even be escaped? Then you can't do that with regexes

Comment: Nope. Atleast can i do it if there are no quotes inside quotes? I can ask API provider to wrap everything in single quote and text wont have single quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
"'.+?(\\s(and|or)\\s).+?'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided there are **no single quotes** in your single quotes then you can use a pattern such as:

```
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("('[^']+')( (and|or) )?");
```

You would then collect all matches in a list as such:

```
final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);

while (m.find())
    matches.add(m.group(1));
```

If there are potential **unescaped** single quotes then this is not doable with regexes. If they *can* be escaped, then have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043454/using-regexes-how-to-efficiently-match-strings-between-double-quotes-with-embed) for a technique to write an efficient regex.