# Extract data from string with regex

Tags: regex

I have s string like this

```
"Country": "FRANCE", "PostalCode": "01, 02, 03"
```

When I use this regex:

```
"(.*)": "(.*)"
```

The system return me only one match with 2 groups

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-32]  `Country": "FRANCE", "PostalCode`
2.  [36-70] `01, 02, 03`
```

What I do wrong ? I would like to get any match value and I can have many "xxx": "yyy" token separated by a comma. So my string can also be

```
"Country": "FRANCE", "PostalCode": "01, 02, 03", "Xxxxx": "yy", "Aaaaa5": "b", "Mmmmmmm": "n1, n2, n3-n30"
```

Comment: Looking for [`"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"\s*:\s*"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/qE0zB3/1)?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I don't want to link this question to a specific language.

Comment: If you know there's no escaped quotes in between quotes and need more performance, use negation mentioned by @MayurKoshti `"([^"]*)"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/nT8uC0/1). Your regex failed [because of greed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) which is addressed by @CladClad answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = '"Country": "FRANCE", "PostalCode": "01, 02, 03"';
REGEX = '/\"([^\"]+)\"\s*\:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/';
preg_match_all(REGEX, $s, $res);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: This one is better, and is the one to be chosen if original strings cannot contain escaped quotes inside.

Comment: Just FYI: no need to escape a colon in any regex flavor I know of (unless it is a regex delimiter, of course :)).

Answer (score 1):

Use this :  `"(.*?)": "(.*?)"` instead as you want the smaller group as possible.

[image]

Comment: I would not use that. It is (almost) the same regex I posted in my comment, but in a lazy dot matching style which is not efficient. Also, it will fail with `"Model": "Some \"Model name\" here"`.

Comment: My solution is just an easy way considering what he will have inside his datas of course it ain't the only solution but it works in most cases ;)

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution for students, not for use in production.

Comment: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed. I didn't knew the combination of * and ? is actually another quantifier that is not just the sum of * and ?.

Comment: @stribizhev How do you know this one is not efficient? What should I avoid?

Comment: @B413: This `*?` is called a *lazy quantifier*, and this one matches 0 or more characters, but as few as necessary to find a valid match. See [*Mastering Quantifiers* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution). This is a poorman's solution that should be replaced with [*unrolling the loop*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17043605/3832970) technique if you plan to use it in production. *How do you know this one is not efficient?* - Compare [this](https://regex101.com/r/qE0zB3/1) (36 steps) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/qE0zB3/2) (92 steps).

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information