# Regexp to read to a plus sign

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the below regexp successfully to read between my tags until I reach a case where there is a `<` sign embedded in my data between the tags.  To fix this I want to read between a `+>` and a `</+`.  There is no way that combination would be used in the database I'm pulling from.  When I try to change the code below to do this I get stuck.  Have any ideas?

Code:

```
@fieldValues =  $inFileLine =~ m(>([^<]+)<)g;
```

My sorry attempt at modifying the code:

```
@fieldValues =  $inFileLine =~ m(\+>([^<\/\+]+)<\/\+)g;
```

Data:

```
<+RecordID+>SWCR000111</+RecordID+><+Title+>My Title Is < Than Yours</+Title+>
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be an embedded `<` somewhere in the sample data? The traditional way to handle this problem is to encode your entities: `&lt;`

Comment: @Matt, my description of the problem is getting cut off.  Sorry about that.  I am hoping to fix my "sorry attempt" so it reads between a +> and a </+.

Comment: Right now my code is just reading between a > and a < which works 99.9 % of the time except in the instance where a title is entered like this "My title is < than yours".

Comment: I don't see a `<` imbedded in the content between tags.

Comment: Sorry about that SLN.  I just fixed it.

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/4FbuRt) - does it work for you? Also, this can work, too: [`\+>(?!<\+)([^<]*(?:<(?!\/\+)[^<]*)*)<\/\+`](https://regex101.com/r/kC4hP8/2).

Comment: ... yurk, this is why in `XML` embedding `<` is disallowed. Of course, neither is this actually `XML` either, so you're getting the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Sobrique - I know this isn't ideal I guess I could come up with another tagging scheme...but Im sure it wouldn't be much prettier.

Comment: @stribizhev - thank you for the code and awesome website.  I was poking around on that site and it's filled with great information.  As a new PERL coder my head is spinning.  I had no idea the regexp for what I needed was so complicated.  Sobrique is right that I need to simplify the data output so I can parse it easier.  Thanks for the lesson and help! -Matt

Comment: @stribizhev - the 2nd one actually worked better.  I had the first one fail on a record for a reason I haven't yet determined.  But the 2nd one seems to be getting through fine.  Thanks again!

Comment: So shall I post it or is sln's answer that works best? I ask because you accepted his answer that is based on tempered greedy token).

Comment: @stribizhev - Right now I am using your second suggestion (\+>(?!<\+)([^<]*(?:<(?!\/\+)[^<]*)*)<\/\+.).  Your first suggestion worked on a small dataset but failed on a larger one probably due to another embedded > or +.  I haven't root-caused it yet.  However your second suggestion has worked without failure yet.  SLNs suggestion worked on a small dataset but I have not had a chance yet to push a large dataset through it yet.

Comment: Thank you for the update. `(?!<\+)` in the 2nd suggestion just makes sure the `+>` is not followed with `<+`. If this rule is universal in your base, I will post with all explanations.

Comment: @stribizhev  - That rule is universal.  The only way that could happen is if the filed I am pulling is blank and I am protecting against that.  I'm not pulling any fields that are blank.  I really appreciate you taking the time out of your busy day to answer my question.  Thank you so much!  Also thank you for that site where I can play with the regular expressions and see the results in real time.  Totally cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works for you as *the `+>` cannot be followed with `<+`*, I am posting my comment as an answer.

This regex should be safe to use even with very large files:

```
\+>(?!<\+)([^<]*(?:<(?!\/\+)[^<]*)*)<\/\+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kC4hP8/2)

Here is what it is doing:

- `\+>(?!<\+)` - matches `+>` (with `\+>`) that is not followed with `<+` (due to the negative lookahead `(?!<\+)`)
- `([^<]*(?:<(?!\/\+)[^<]*)*)` - matches *and stores in Group 1*

  - `[^<]*` - 0 or more characters other than `<` followed by...
  - `(?:<(?!\/\+)[^<]*)*` -  0 or more sequences of...

    - `<(?!\/\+)` - `<` that is not followed by `/+` and then
    - `[^<]*` - 0 or more characters other than `<`
- `<\/\+` - matches the final `</+`

In short, this is the same as `\+>(?!<\+)([\s\S]*?)<\/\+`, but "unwrapped" using the *unrolling-the-loop* technique to allow large portions of text in-between the delimiters (that is, between `+>` and the closest `</+`).

Comment: Awesome.  I'm going to get a cup of coffee and study this.  You as well as all others that responded are genius!  My script is processing very large amounts of text between the delimiters for a few of the fields in my record.  Probably explains why the second option worked better.  Thank you!

Comment: If you want to study unroll the loop technique, here is [one link](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) and an [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043454/using-regexes-how-to-efficiently-match-strings-between-double-quotes-with-embed).

Answer (score 0):

**update**:  Since you are just looking for simple, you don't have to
go beyond the definition of tag delimiters.
This is because you don't parse with a definition of a *tag* at all.

The solution boils down to this very simple regex -

Find:  `<(?!/?\+)`
Replace: `&lt;`

---

*If you want to proceed with a misconception that `+> .. </+` delineates

something between tags, this is the original.*

---

Typically it's done with negative assertions on a character by character basis.

`m{\+>((?:(?!\+>|</\+).)*<(?:(?!\+>|</\+).)*)</\+}s`

Formatted:

```
 \+>
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?! \+> | </\+ )
           . 
      )*
      <
      (?:
           (?! \+> | </\+ )
           . 
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 </\+
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 42 , len 29 ) 
+>My Title Is < Than Yours</+  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 44 , len 24 ) 
My Title Is < Than Yours
```

Comment: Thanks SLN.  This is really cool and a great lesson.  A little over my head still but I am goggling :)  Thank you sir!

Comment: With the best will in the world - whilst it is a valid answer to your problem - it will make future maintenance programmers really hate you.

Comment: I agree that these solutions are terribly complicated but Im not sure I have an alternative.  I'm talking with a clearquest database and need to request and push data in a very specific way through their business logic layer.  I can't go directly to the SQL server database.  And I'm also not allowed to install PERL packages above what is already there do to extreme security standards, red tape, and politics.

Comment: @Matt - I posted a terribly _simple_ solution for ya.