# How to find the opposite char in a python string?

Tags: python, string, search, find

Such as there is a string s:

```
s = "((abc)((123))())blabla"
```

We know the beginning of s is "(" and we want to find the opposite of it, the ")" before "blabla", how to do this in python?

Is it possible to do this in a simple and intuitive way, without using status machines?
or is there any library can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624 This might help

Comment: nope, i fear that you cannot escape regular expressions with this kind of problem

Comment: @AmitMizrahi thank you very much, that is a good way. So the question should be changed to is there any lib to do this kind of things..

Comment: I've never used it, but you could probably do something like this with `pyparsing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try regex, pyparsing, but a naive option with linear time complexity is the following naive way

```
>>> s = "((abc)((123))())blabla"
>>> count = 0
>>> for i,e in enumerate(s):
    if e == '(':
        count += 1
    elif e == ')':
        count -= 1
    if not count:
        break


>>> s[:i + 1]
'((abc)((123))())'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

by code you can achieve that by:

```
from collections import defaultdict

opens = defaultdict(int)

open_close_pair = []

s = '((abc)((123))())blabla'
openc, closec = '(', ')'

for c in range(0, len(s)):
    if s[c] == openc:
        # +1 in every entry
        for key, val in opens.items():
            opens[key] += 1
        opens[c] += 1

    elif s[c] == closec:
        # -1 in every entery
        for key, val in opens.items():
            opens[key] -= 1
    else:   
        pass

    for key, val in opens.items():
        if val == 0:
            # open the entry to the open close pairs
            open_close_pair.append( (key, c))
            # the bracket is close so can be removed from the counter
            del opens[key]

for x in open_close_pair:
    print " %s %s " % (s[x[0]], s[x[1]])
print open_close_pair 
print opens
```

The output is:

```
 ( ) 
 ( ) 
 ( ) 
 ( ) 
 ( ) 
[(1, 5), (7, 11), (6, 12), (13, 14), (0, 15)]
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
```

The algorithm is:

- keep an **opens** dict containing the position of open brackets.
- When you find an open bracket, you add +1 on all the previous entries and than add a new entry for the current position
- When you find a closing bracket, you decrease -1 on all the previous enteries
- Just run through the **opens** and if any entry is 0 means that we have a pair.