# How to parse last parenthesis?

Tags: java, regex

So if I have an expression enclosed by a pair of parenthesis with anything in between or outside the parenthesis, how can I remove the outermost pair of parenthesis, use recursion and call parseFactor (every time I see a set of parenthesis I call parseFactor)? Since this is very vague, I'll give you an example of what I mean. Take this JUST FOR EXAMPLE (It is not a specific problem I am trying to solve, just a general idea):
If I have the expression

`((4+1)*1) + 5`

I want to break this down so that I first get `(4+1)*1` (Whatever is in the first pair of parenthesis). Then, call the parseFactor function again because I see another set of parenthesis, and then parseFactor, which calls parseExpression, will do the calculations inside using recursion. So that means I get `5*1`. I then do the calculations of that with the function parseTerm and get `5`. Once I get out of the recursion I get `5+5` I then call another function called parseExpression, which will calculate 5+5 and return 10.

Currently, I am using `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*)").matcher(expr)).find()` in parseFactor and then group the result to remove the first parenthesis, leading me with `(4+1)*1) + 5`. I call parseFactor again to get 4+1)*1) + 5. The problem is I don't know how to get rid of the outer parenthesis. Here's my code for reference, if anyone needs it:

```
else if(Pattern.matches("\\(.*", expr)){
    (m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
    String save = m.group(1);
    (m = Pattern.compile("\\)(.*)").matcher(expr)).find();
    String remainder = m.group(1);
    int length = save.length();
    int rLength = remainder.length();
    save = save.substring(0, length - (rLength));
    expr = parseExpr(save);
    int i = findInt(expr);
    String value = Integer.toString(i);
    expr = value + remainder;
    (m = Pattern.compile("\\)(.*)").matcher(save)).find();
}
```

where expr is the string to be parsed and broken down and calculated. This code came from my parseExpression function. findInt() just returns the first integer it finds within the string.

EDIT: I have to use regex.

Comment: So, do you just want to evaluate the mathematical expression?

Comment: Yes, that's what it basically boils down to. But I need to use regex.

Comment: @user1831442.. Regex is not the right tool to go for. It is not good for parsing meaningful expressions. It can only parse Regular Languages, not beyond that. You should use some parser to parse the mathematical expression, like http://code.google.com/p/symja/wiki/MathExpressionParser from google. You can find many of them online.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is kind of overdo for this kind of operation. Since `JDK1.6`, you can use the built-in `Javascript engine`. Try using it if possible.

It can be basically acheived as below using [ScriptEngine.eval(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String foo = "((4+1)*1) + 5";
System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use this actually, because I have some specificalities that I did not mention. Instead of a number, I might have something like D[1], where I have to get the value inside D[1]. This won't work.

Comment: Will D[1] will be available in the input string? Why cant you construct the proper evaluating equation and use ScriptEngine for the string. I still feel you can acheive without Regex.

Comment: @user1831442 what do you mean by "I might have something like D[1], where I have to get the value inside D[1]"

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should match a parenthesis group, with anything inside:

```
\\(.*\\)
```

Note: the double backslash is because of Java escaping characters, the regex actually is "(.*)", without quotes.

However, it seems that you are trying to parse expressions, and regex is not the right tool for that, so you should consider using a parser for it. Things like ensuring parenthesis balance cannot be done in Java through regex, so it will be very difficult to ensure the correctness of the expressions, maybe not even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, using Regex are wrong for your intentions because you are dealing with nested structures, i.e. recursion. And regular expression is unable to do this. To explain this, You should first understand that a finite automaton (which is the data structure underlying a regular expression) does not have memory apart from the state it's in, and if you have arbitrarily deep nesting, you need an arbitrarily large automaton, which collides with the notion of a finite automaton.

But there is a very simple [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524624/1365960) to complete your job.

Answer (score 0):

public class T_1{

```
String c[];
Stack<String> s1 = new Stack<String>();
Stack<String> s2 = new Stack<String>();
int top = 0;

/**
 * Description:构造函数
 * 
 * @param expression
 *            :表达式字符串
 */
public T_1(String expression) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    char chare[] = expression.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int start = 0;
    while (count < chare.length) {
        if (!judgeNum(new String(new char[] { chare[count] }))) {
            if (i != 0) {
                char c1[] = new char[i];
                System.arraycopy(chare, start, c1, 0, i);
                al.add(new String(c1));
            }
            al.add(new String(new char[] { chare[count] }));
            i = 0;
            start = count + 1;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if (judgeNum(new String(new char[] { chare[--count] }))) {
        al.add(new String(new char[] { chare[count] }));
    }
    // c=(String[])(al.toArray());
    System.out.println(al.toString());
    c = new String[al.size()];
    i = 0;
    for (Object o : al.toArray()) {
        c[i++] = o.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * Description:转换,c为中缀表达式
 */
public void transition() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < c.length) {
        if (s1.empty()) {
            s1.push(c[i]);
        } else {
            if (judgeNum(c[i])) {
                s1.push(c[i]);
            } else if (judgeOperate(c[i])) {
                if (s2.isEmpty()) {
                    s2.push(c[i]);
                } else if (judgeLP(s2.peek())) {
                    s2.push(c[i]);
                } else if (judgePriority(c[i], s2.peek())) {
                    s2.push(c[i]);
                } else {
                    s1.push(s2.pop());
                    while (!s2.isEmpty() && !s2.peek().equals("(")) {
                        if (!judgePriority(c[i], s2.peek())) {
                            s1.push(s2.pop());
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    s2.push(c[i]);
                }
            } else if (judgeLP(c[i])) {
                s2.push(c[i]);
            } else if (judgeRP(c[i])) {
                while (true) {
                    String c_1 = s2.pop();
                    if (!judgeLP(c_1)) {
                        s1.push(c_1);
                        System.out.println("c_1" + c_1);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (!s2.isEmpty()) {
        String c_1 = s2.pop();
        if (!judgeLP(c_1)) {
            s1.push(c_1);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param c
 * @return:是否是数字
 */
public boolean judgeNum(String c) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(c);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * 
 * @param c
 * @return:是否是运算符
 */
public boolean judgeOperate(String c) {
    if (c.equals("+") || c.equals("-") || c.equals("*") || c.equals("/")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param c
 * @return:是否是左括号
 */
public boolean judgeLP(String c) {
    if (c.equals("(")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param c
 * @return:是否是右括号
 */
public boolean judgeRP(String c) {
    if (c.equals(")")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return:是否a的优先级大于b
 */
public boolean judgePriority(String a, String b) {
    if ((a.equals("*") || a.equals("/"))
            && (b.equals("+") || b.equals("-"))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * 运算
 */
public void operate() {
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    /*
     * while(!judgeNum(s2.peek())){ s1.push(s2.pop()); }
     */
    System.out.println(s1.toString());
    System.out.println(s2.toString());
    while (!s2.isEmpty()) {
        String s = s2.pop();
        if (judgeNum(s)) {
            s1.push(s);
        } else {
            String a = s1.pop();
            String b = s1.pop();
            s1.push(operate_(b, a, s));
            System.out.println(s1.peek());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s1.pop());
}

public String operate_(String a, String b, String c) {
    int ia = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int ib = Integer.parseInt(b);
    if (c.equals("+")) {
        return String.valueOf(ia + ib);
    } else if (c.equals("-")) {
        return String.valueOf(ia - ib);
    } else if (c.equals("*")) {
        return String.valueOf(ia * ib);
    } else if (c.equals("/")) {
        return String.valueOf(ia / ib);
    }
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("请输入表达式!");
    T_1 t = new T_1(s);// "1+2+3*1+(2-1*4)*2+2"
    t.transition();
    t.operate();
}
```

}