# How to split arguments for function call

Tags: java, regex, string

I've got a String that represents a function call that I'm trying to parse.  Each argument can either be another function call, or a single word.  I would like to write an algorithm that will retrieve the name, and split the args.

```
class FunctionCall{
   String name;
   String[] args;
}

function parseFunction(String func){
    FunctionCall fc = new FunctionCall();
    fc.name = func.subString(0,func.indexOf("("))
    fc.args = ???
}
```

A function call could look like `func1(func2(arg1, arg2),func3(func4(arg3)),arg4)`, and I would like `String[] args` to contain `func2(arg1, arg2)`, `func3(func4(arg3))`, and `arg4`.

I don't believe this is possible with regex due to the recursive nature of function calls.

I writing the code in Java, but other languages would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524624/1769273)

I need to parse the characters one by one, and count the number of opening parenthesis.  If I come across a comma when no parenthesis is open, then I should split on that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^[^\(\)]*?\()?(?:(.*?\)),|(.*?)\)$)
```

You can try this.It is matching the current input.Might require more input patterns to test.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/31