# Regex for getting values inside nested brace

Tags: javascript, regex

Following is the string I am using

```
(((Thermal) WN RR) AND ((Energy) SS AB)), Text only
```

Above text need to be converted to

```
Thermal AND Energy
```

How to achieve this.  This should be generic like this should also work if the value is

```
((Thermal) WN TR)
((Thermal) WN RR) AND ((Energy) SS AB) OR ((Thermal) WN RR)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

**Solution:**
Thank to @spOOm Using his regex, following is the code I used to solve the issue

```
q = <Query String>
q =     q.substring(0, q.lastIndexOf(')')+1);
q =     q.replace(/\(\(([^()]+)\)(?: [^()]+)+\)/g, "$1");
```

The first setup could be done by Regex but I am not a pro at regex.  Thank you all..

Comment: What should be the output of the long input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `\(\(([^()]+)\)(?: [A-Z]+)+\)` by `$1` may suit your needs:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SaFa7GUmHWvtD1L0)

---

In JavaScript:

```js
var output = input.replace(/\(\(([^()]+)\)(?: [A-Z]+)+\)/g, "$1");
```

Comment: Hi, your code works great.  I did a minor tweak and got what I want.  I will update my answer with it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Please see my answer if we could solve the first string operation too with Regex it would be great.  Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you want to get the innermost values in nested braces you can use this:

```
/\(((?:(?>[^\(]))*?)\)/g
```

It will capture all characters between "(" and ")" with the condition that there are no other "(" characters in between

In your last example it would capture

Thermal Thermal Thermal Energy Thermal

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS0jV2/2)

**EDIT**

If you need to match outside the nested braces too you can use this:

```
/\(((?:(?>[^\(]))*?)\)|\)((?:(?>[^\)]))*?)\(/g
```

I just added the same regex inverting the braces

In your last example it would match

Thermal , Thermal , Thermal AND Energy OR Thermal

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS0jV2/3)

Comment: Thank you @marco this work perfectly in PHP but '?.' not working in Javascript.  Do you know how to get it working in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a regex, since I believe you are talking about arbitrarily nested braces. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: Or do you have a code to achieve this feature.. I am struggling for few hours..:) tnx in advance.. Using Javascript

Comment: This problem might be harder than you expect. You're looking for some sort of recursive parser. Try using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624) to extract brackets, and parse it recursively.

Comment: We're stepping into the territory of generating a [Parse Tree](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc/spr10/slides/cfl2.pdf).

Comment: Please see the solution above.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you want the inner-most values, use this pattern

```
\(([^()]+)\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/275)

```
\(              # "("
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^()]         # Character not in [()] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
\)              # ")"
```

Comment: But he also wants the `AND` or `OR`s that are nested.