# Discarding garbage characters after json object with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have to consume a so called web service implemented by a dumb monkey which is returning some garbage after the proper Json response.
Something like this:

```
{
  "Property1": 1,
  "Property2": 2,
  "Property3": 3
}<?xml version='1.0' ?>Maybe some other gibberish nonsense I wish to discard.
```

Now, I could just search for `"<?xml"` and split, but I was wondering if I can use a stream reader or something to read **up to** the closing `}` and then discard the rest.

I'm using C# and Json.Net.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the substring `<?xml` won't be part of things inside the json? Like `{ "Property1": "<?xml version='1.0'>" ... }<?xml version='1.0'>....` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624 Look at the propsed solution, it's based on counting opening/closing brackets

Comment: I would like a robust solution. Given Json.Net has many advanced readers, I was wondering if using one of them instead of the standard JsonConvert I could get a JToken or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set [`JsonSerializerSettings.CheckAdditionalContent = false`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_CheckAdditionalContent.htm) to tell the serializer to ignore any content after the end of the deserialized JSON object:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, long>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { CheckAdditionalContent = false })
```

Oddly enough it is necessary to do this explicitly despite the fact that the default value seems to be `false` already, since the [underlying field is nullable](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializerSettings.cs#L73).

Comment: [Here specifically](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6d7c94e69fa2f52b91fb22972321cb9b51b9abed/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L856-L859) are the lines of code that are the culprit of requiring you to explicitly set the value to false.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - yes, there's something a bit awkward going on here with how this setting interacts with [`JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm).  I have a feeling `CheckAdditionalContent` was added later in such a way that `JsonConvert` would error by default when encountering additional content, but [fragment loops](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm) would not.

Answer (score 1):

I knew there had to be a simple and robust way:

```
    public T ReadTypeAndDiscardTheRest<T>(string json)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var token = JToken.Load(jsonReader);

            return token.ToObject<T>();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestJsonDiscarding()
    {
        var json = @"{""Key"":""a"", ""Value"":""n""}<?xml>aaaa";
        var kp = ReadTypeAndDiscardTheRest<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(json);

        Assert.That(kp.Key, Is.EqualTo("a"));
        Assert.That(kp.Value, Is.EqualTo("n"));
    }
```

As always, Json.Net FTW.