# System.Text.Json parse document that exists internal to a string

Tags: json, parsing, system.text.json

I receive string content that starts with a JSON value (could be simple or complex) and has some additional content afterward.  I'd like to be able to parse the JSON document.

I don't have control over the string, so I can't put any kind of delimiter after the JSON content that would enable me to isolate it.

Examples:

```
"true and some more" - yields <true>
"false this is different" - yields <false>
"5.6/7" - yields <5.6>
"\"a string\""; then this" - yields <"a string">
"[null, true]; and some more" - yields <[null, true]>
"{\"key\": \"value\"}, then the end" - yields <{"key": "value"}>
```

The issue is the trailing content.  The parser expects the input to end and throws an exception:

```
')' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data.
```

There isn't an option in `JsonDocumentOptions` to allow trailing content.

As a bonus, if you can give a solution that uses `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, that'd be aweseme.

Comment: You can do this with [tag:json.net] via the `CheckAdditionalContent` setting, see [Discarding garbage characters after json object with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37172263/3744182).  There's nothing built into [tag:system.text.json] to do this though.  Maybe `Utf8JsonStreamReader` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/3744182) to [Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182) might do what you need, possibly with appropriate tweaks...

Comment: Huh, `Utf8JsonStreamReader` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/3744182) to [Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182) by [mtosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7217527/mtosh) actually works as-is!  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/o9Ctba.  Didn't really expect that actually.  Mark as a duplicate, or add as an answer?

Comment: You can't deserialize from a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` using `System.Text.Json` though, you can only deserialize from byte spans, sequences or streams.  That's because it's designed to deserialize directly from Utf8 byte sequences, not char sequences.

Comment: I explicitly stated that I'm using System.Text.Json. Suggesting another library isn't a viable solution.

Comment: I'll give the custom reader a try, but I'd prefer that I don't have to convert _back_ into a string having already converted the source string into the span for processing.

Comment: *I'd prefer that I don't have to convert back into a string* -- No choice there.  `JsonSerializer` and `Utf8JsonReader` work only with byte sequences or spans, so either you do it or the library does it internally.  When you call [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.String.cs#L86) internally the library is encoding to utf8, then deserializing from that.

Comment: Hmm. That answer is specifically for deserializing into an object.  I need parsing into a JsonElement.

Comment: That's shown in the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o9Ctba).  Just deserialize to a `JsonElement`: `jsonStreamReader.Deserialize<JsonElement>()`,

Comment: Okay.  So I see the tests, but for some reason, my specific test case isn't working.  I have a number followed by a close parenthesis `1)`.  I see that `5.6/7` works just fine, but I still get the error for the `)`.

Comment: It's something inside `JsonReader.Read()` that doesn't like the `)`.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I figured out why your test cases work: they all use valid JSON characters (`/` is valid for comments).  If you add a test case that contains a character that's invalid for JSON, e.g. `+`, `_`, `)`, or `g`, the test fails.  (Not sure why `;` works.)... maybe.  `:` also breaks it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222136/discussion-between-gregsdennis-and-dbc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested answer of the custom reader wasn't working for me because the problem existed in the base reader: it just doesn't like certain trailing characters.

Since I still wanted to rely on `JsonDocument.Parse()` to extract the element for me, I really just needed to find where the element stopped break that bit off as a separate piece and submit that to the parse method.  Here's what I came up with:

```cs
public static bool TryParseJsonElement(this ReadOnlySpan<char> span, ref int i, out JsonElement element)
{
    try
    {
        int end = i;
        char endChar;
        switch (span[i])
        {
            case 'f':
                end += 5;
                break;
            case 't':
            case 'n':
                end += 4;
                break;
            case '.': case '-': case '0':
            case '1': case '2': case '3':
            case '4': case '5': case '6':
            case '7': case '8': case '9':
                end = i;
                var allowDash = false;
                while (end < span.Length && (span[end].In('0'..'9') ||
                                             span[end].In('e', '.', '-')))
                {
                    if (!allowDash && span[end] == '-') break;
                    allowDash = span[end] == 'e';
                    end++;
                }
                break;
            case '\'':
            case '"':
                end = i + 1;
                endChar = span[i];
                while (end < span.Length && span[end] != endChar)
                {
                    if (span[end] == '\\')
                    {
                        end++;
                        if (end >= span.Length) break;
                    }
                    end++;
                }

                end++;
                break;
            case '{':
            case '[':
                end = i + 1;
                endChar = span[i] == '{' ? '}' : ']';
                var inString = false;
                while (end < span.Length)
                {
                    var escaped = false;
                    if (span[end] == '\\')
                    {
                        escaped = true;
                        end++;
                        if (end >= span.Length) break;
                    }
                    if (!escaped && span[end] == '"')
                    {
                        inString = !inString;
                    }
                    else if (!inString && span[end] == endChar) break;

                    end++;
                }

                end++;
                break;
            default:
                element = default;
                return false;
        }
        
        var block = span[i..end];
        if (block[0] == '\'' && block[^1] == '\'')
            block = $"\"{block[1..^1].ToString()}\"".AsSpan();
        element = JsonDocument.Parse(block.ToString()).RootElement;
        i = end;
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        element = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

It doesn't care so much about what's in the middle except (for strings, objects, and arrays) to know whether it's in the middle of a string (where it would be valid for the end character to be found) and checking for `\`-delimited characters.  It works well enough for my purposes.

It takes a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` and an integer by reference.  `i` needs to be the start of the expected JSON value, and it will be advanced to the next character after, if a valid value is found.  It also follows the standard `Try*` pattern of returning a `bool` with an output parameter for the value.