# Matching and replacing function expressions

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, backreference

I need to do some very light parsing of C# (actually [transpiled Razor code](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Test/CodeGenerators/RazorChunkGeneratorTest.cs#L194)) to replace a list of function calls with textual replacements.

If given a set containing `{"Foo.myFunc" : "\"def\"" }` it should replace this code:

```
var res = "abc" + Foo.myFunc(foo, Bar.otherFunc( Baz.funk()));
```

with this:

```
var res = "abc" + "def"
```

I don't care about the nested expressions.

This seems fairly trivial and I think I should be able to avoid building an entire C# parser using something like this for every member of the mapping set:

- find expression start (e.g. `Foo.myFunc`)
- `Push()`/`Pop()` parentheses on a `Stack` until `Count == 0`.
- Mark this as expression stop
- replace everything from expression start until expression stop

But maybe I don't need to ... Is there a (possibly built-in) .NET library that can do this for me? Counting is not possible in the family of languages that RE is in, but maybe the *extended* regex syntax in C# can handle this somehow using back references?

**edit:**
As the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524624/200987) demonstrates simply counting brackets will not be sufficient generally, as something like `trollMe("(")` will throw off those algorithms. Only true parsing would then suffice, I guess (?).

Comment: If this is a one-off couldn't you just start with a regex for N matched parentheses, then N-1, ... until you've got them all?

Comment: This sounds like a job for the [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) library.

Comment: @IanMercer Possibly? Not sure how to do that... According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html#balanced .NET does not support recursive regexes, but it does support "balancing constructs" which should be a good fit. I just don't know how to use them.

Comment: @RaymondChen It absolutely would be a better solution, but it also seems a bit complex to dig into the roslyn docs to find out how to work with the AST. Would you happen to know how to work with it? There are no answers here yet ...

Comment: @IanMercer As this is supposed to handle all kinds of code thrown at it (https://github.com/fatso83/razor-cli/issues/5), it should not barf at `print("(");`, which a regex would ... But maybe it could be a start?

Comment: [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904670.aspx) walks through a program that rewrites regular expressions, but the same principle can be used to rewrite anything else. You would look for a MemberAccessExpressionSyntax and see if it's one you want to replace. That said, it is likely overkill if this is just a one-off thing. (On the other hand, writing a C# parser is not fun.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah, that seems like a nice intro. I was browsing the FAQ and the unit test code for Roslyn and came across some usable example code, so maybe I can pair the two and make something usable. Example source code for the  Roslyn FAQ: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Samples/CSharp/APISampleUnitTests/FAQ.cs#L366

Comment: If the code is that complex that it can contain parentheses inside quotes then Roslyn is sounding like the best bet here, especially if this isn't a one off where you can "run 10 regex replaces in sequence with N, N-1, ... parentheses to get most of them fixed, clean up a couple" and be done.

Comment: Depending on how antagonistic the code base is, you might might or might not need to worry about `Namespace.Foo.myFunc(...)`, (which you want to replace) vs. `UnrelatedNamespace.Foo.myFunc(...)`. (which you don't). Or worse, `using UnrelatedNamespace; Foo.myFunc(...)`. Or `Foo` + newline + `/* now call myFunc */ .myFunc(...)` - a method call split across multiple lines. Or aliases: `using Foo = UnrelatedNamespace.Bar; Foo.myFunc(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The trick for a normal string will be:

```
(?>"(\\"|[^"])*")
```

A verbatim string:

```
(?>@"(""|[^"])*")
```

Maybe this can help, but I'm not sure that this will work in all cases:

```
<func>(?=\()((?>/\*.*?\*/)|(?>@"(""|[^"])*")|(?>"(\\"|[^"])*")|\r?\n|[^()"]|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))+?(?(open)(?!))
```

Replace `<func>` with your function name.

Useless to say that `trollMe("\"(", "((", @"abc""de((f")` works as expected.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/DhNKC5)

Comment: Wow, that is pretty impressive. Before going down the Roslyn path I could just do multiple passes of the source code and the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag. Should be ok in 95% of the cases.

Comment: @oligofren Do you have an example of something that doesn't work? I think that newlines could be added.

Comment: Regex changed to handle newlines.

Comment: Watch out for false positives inside comments. `Foo.myFunc(0 /* ") */)` - maybe that's not a problem in this specific case.