# C# Regex search for dotted functions and their arguments

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I need to search for all occurrences of chained C#-like functions in a text string.  For example, I would like to break out each method and its parenthetical arguments of a string such as this:

```
object.method(1, "2", abc).method2().method3("test(), 1, 2, 3").method4("\"Hi\"")
```

Here is the regex pattern I almost had working:

```
(?<objectName>[^\}]*?)\.(?<methodName>[^\}]*?)\(((?:[^;"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)*?\)
```

This extracts the objectName and the first methodName correctly, but lumps

> 1, "2", abc).method2().method3("test, 1, 2, 3").method4("\"Hi\""

all into the third argument as "$1".

My latest approach was to divide and conquer by removing the objectName specification as that is easy to parse out. This lead me to using:

```
\.(?<methodName>[^(]*?)\(((?:[^;"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)*?\)
```

Which yields similar results as before obviously without the objectName. I did this to see if I could get a global result but could get the right regex syntax.

In summary, I need to parse out multiple chained .method(parameters) occurrences into their constituent parts named "methodName" and "parameters". I have deduced a few things but my regex skills are quite rusty at best and am unable to overcome this at this time. I appreciate any help you may have to offer.

I have been using this site for testing: http://regexstorm.net/tester

UPDATE: To clarify, the requirements do not include supporting C# lambda expressions, only the dotted function syntax. This is not intended to be a full C# parser. The only need is the dotted method chaining. I apologize for any confusion. The pattern I was looking to breakout is:

```
object.method(arguments).method(arguments).method(arguments)...
```

My approach to this was to first extract the object name which is a simple operation that does not require the use of Regex. This would now leave the following for Regex parsing into two constituent parts:

```
.method(arguments).method(arguments).method(arguments)...
```

Which would yield:

```
method   arguments
method   arguments
method   arguments
...
```

*arguments* may be null (missing), as in .method(), or method may actually be a property (no parentheses and arguments), as in:

```
.method.method().method(arguments)
```

Which would yield:

```
method   (null)
method   (string.Empty)
method   arguments
```

*arguments* would contain everything between the opening and closing parentheses; these do not need to be parsed out at this time as those would be processed in a subsequent Regex operation.

This seems to me to be within the capability of Regex to detect this simple pattern of dot-method-openPar-argumentsStr-closePar next dot-method-openPar-argumentsStr-closePar and so forth.

This is the extent of the grammar - no comments, no lambda - just object.method(arguments).method()...

I hope this helps.

Comment: Every () creates a group, in the order of the "(". Have you tried using higher $'s like "$2" or "$3" to see if they contain they desired output?

Comment: Your hope will crumble when I introduce you this chain: 'method1(").ToString()").method2(1).method3(").Fail()")'

Comment: I answered a very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37314847/2729609) some time ago. The regex is going to be very large.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be properly done through regex, because your arguments is just too unpredictable, and regex grammar level is uncomparable with C# parser grammar. For example, it can contain string with any content:

```
method1("x.hiThere().lol()").method2()
```

it can nest:

```
method1(x=>method2().method3())
```

it can just do this:

```
a("b().c()",d=> d(").hi()"))
```

For you problem solution you need to learn about [Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser), and write C# grammar for this particular task. In terms of frameworks you can start from [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) project.

**Explanation**

The reason because you can't do this is grammar type differences.
Regex is using regular language and is **Type-3** in Chomsky hierarchy.
C# is using context-free language and is **Type-2** in Chomsky hierarchy.

If you represent it visualy, C# is much more powerful language than Regex language:

[image]

For example, your case fall into *pit of parsers* is just because of lambda's in C#:

```
method1(x=>
{
    ....
    /* some code here */
    ....
}).method2()
```

Comment: I'm with you that this should not be solved using regex but the posted problems are able to [handle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37314847/2729609).

Comment: The case I created this answer is fundamental. Regex grammar is Type-3 grammar (Regular), on the other hand C# grammar - Type-2 grammar (Context-free). It means there always be cases when Regex grammar can't represent C# grammar.

Comment: Thanks @ecron06. Excellent info on parsing science. I have updated the original post to limit the scope of problem.  The C# reference was simply used for illustrative purposes to frame the problem. I do appreciate your answer.

Comment: Does anyone else have additional thoughts/ideas given the clarified limited scope?