# Extract a N sequence of a string text that lies between N Brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

every day I received this kind of email is automatically generated
my goal is a regular expression or scripting code to select all the text between two outer brackets.

example: test test test (a) (b) (aaaaa ( bbbb (cccc)) dddd (ee) fff) test test test

result :(a) (b) (aaaaa ( bbbb (cccc)) dddd (ee) fff)

this is the body Email:

> All documents are reproduced with the permission of the copyright
>   owner.  Further reproduction or distribution is prohibited without
>   permission. Please do not reply directly to this email.
>   *ProQuest Search alert* ProQuest Dialog will send alerts *Daily* to:
>   *Email address:* productcostumer@sap.com
>   *Alert name:* Competitors
>   *Alert ID:* 560083
>   *Dates of coverage:* March 15 2018 through March 16 2018
>   *Created by My Research account:* Jack(Smith Jack)
>
> *Subject:* (ti,ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*))  OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere  near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR
>   (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage  P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR
>   ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10  (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR
>   *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter) near/2  AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman* near/5  Access) OR (Access*
>   p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0 flex)) OR  (UniCel* p/1...
>   *Alert keywords:* Competitors
>
> at ProQuest Dialog. See documents in available formats (e.g., 
>   Citation/Abstract, Full text, etc.). Export documents to PDF, RTF,
>   XML,  etc.
>
> 1 new documents found for (ti,ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR 
>   analy* OR *array*)) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR
>   (CELL  p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR
>   *array*)) OR  (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR ((Beckman* p/1  Coulter near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy*
>   OR *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0  Coulter) near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel*
>   P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR (  Beckman* near/5 Access) OR
>   (Access* p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0  flex)) OR (UniCel*
>   p/1 DxH) OR ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR Coulter*LH)) OR  ((Ortho p/0
>   Clinical P/1 Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros* p/1 System*) OR 
>   (VITROS* p/1 ECiQ) OR ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION) OR (ORTHO p/1 
>   AutoVue*)) OR ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR HemosIL OR ACLTOP
>   OR  (ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEM*OPL) OR ((Radiometer
>   near/10  (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0 FLEX)
>   OR (ABL?? p/0  FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) OR
>   StatStrip OR (STAT p/0  PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1
>   Prime) OR STATPROFILE*) OR  (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay*
>   OR test* OR analy* OR *array*))  OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension
>   p/0 Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT))) and  (ud(>20170101)) (see attachment)
>
> *All ProQuest Dialog alert emails are sent from*: alert@proquest.com. Tip:  use this email address to set up a filter and direct ProQuest
>   Dialog alert  mail to a folder other than your inbox.

this is my script code:

```
var messageBody = message.getPlainBody();
var ssFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.getId()).addFile(ssFile);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(ssFile);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.insertColumnAfter(sheet.getLastColumn());
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn() + 1)
var values = range.getValues();
values[0][sheet.getLastColumn()] = "Search Strategy";
for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

var y = messageBody.match(/\((.*)\)/ig); //my regexp to extract the the text between ()
if (y)



   values[i][values[i].length - 1] = y.toString();
    }
range.setValues(values);
```

this result that i expected :

> (ti,ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR array)) OR
>   (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)) OR ((Alere
>   near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR array)) OR (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage
>   P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10
>   (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR array)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter)
>   near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman*
>   near/5 Access) OR (Access* p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0
>   flex)) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxH) OR ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR CoulterLH)) OR
>   ((Ortho p/0 Clinical P/1 Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros p/1
>   System*) OR (VITROS* p/1 ECiQ) OR ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION) OR
>   (ORTHO p/1 AutoVue*)) OR ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR
>   HemosIL OR ACLTOP OR (ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEMOPL)
>   OR ((Radiometer near/10 (assay OR test* OR analy* OR array)) OR (AQT??
>   p/0 FLEX) OR (ABL?? p/0 FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical)
>   OR StatStrip OR (STAT p/0 PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1
>   Prime) OR STATPROFILE*) OR (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay*
>   OR test* OR analy* OR array)) OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0
>   Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT)))

the wrong Parse:

> (Smith Jack),(ti,ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR
>   *array*)),(Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0 DYN)),(assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)),(assay* OR test* OR
>   analy* OR *array*)) OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter),(UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR
>   (UniCel* p/1 DxI),(Access* p/1 Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0
>   flex)),(Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care),((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR
>   analy* OR *array*)),(Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR
>   Afinion),(assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)),(UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR
>   (UniCel* p/1 DxI),(Access* p/1 Systeme),(UniCel* p/1 DxH) OR
>   ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR Coulter*LH)),((Ortho p/0 Clinical P/1
>   Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros* p/1 System*),(VITROS* p/1 ECiQ) OR
>   ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION),((Instrumentation p/0
>   Laboratories),(ACL p/0 ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR
>   GEM*OPL),(assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0
>   FLEX),((Nova p/0 Biomedical),((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1 Prime) OR
>   STATPROFILE*),(((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay* OR test* OR
>   analy* OR *array*)),(ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0 Vista) OR
>   RAPIDPOINT))),(ud(>20170101)) (see attachment)

Any help will be gratefully received

Comment: RE can't match that. You need a pushdown automata. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624

Comment: but this question was 9 years ago.. now there is new version for RE

Comment: @Moka I believe JavaScript still lacks this feature (recursion).