# return multiple matches using re.match or re.search

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython

I am converting some code to [micropython](http://micropython.org) and I got stuck on a particular regular expression.

In python my code is

```
import re

line = "0-1:24.2.1(180108205500W)(00001.290*m3)"
between_brackets = '\(.*?\)' 

brackettext  = re.findall(between_brackets, line) 
gas_date_str = read_date_time(brackettext[0])
gas_val      = read_gas(brackettext[1])

# gas_date_str and gas_val take the string between brackets 
# and return a value that can later be used
```

micropython only implements [a limited set of re functions](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/ure.html)

how do I achieve the same with only the limited functions available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something along the following lines. Repeatedly use `re.search` while consuming the string. The implementation here uses a generator function:

```
import re

def findall(pattern, string):
    while True:
        match = re.search(pattern, string)
        if not match:
            break
        yield match.group(0)
        string = string[match.end():]

>>> list(findall(r'\(.*?\)', "0-1:24.2.1(180108205500W)(00001.290*m3)"))
['(180108205500W)', '(00001.290*m3)']
```

Comment: I like the compactness of the code and the use of yield.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that while match.end is in the core MicroPython library, its implementation varies from port to port. So for example on PyCom boards... there is no .end(). (as of today anyway)

Comment: I was missing this one out while tinkering with [micropython regex](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/re.html) - so this helps a lot! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can write a method using `re.search()` that returns a list of all matches:

```
import re  

def find_all(regex, text):
    match_list = []
    while True:
        match  = re.search(regex, text)
        if match:
            match_list.append(match.group(0))
            text = text[match.end():]
        else:
            return match_list
```

Also, note that your `between_brackets` regex will not take care of nested brackets:

```
re.findall('\(.*?\)', "(ac(ssc)xxz)")
>>> ['(ac(ssc)']
```

Comment: thank you. perhaps even more elegant would be to make the match statement the condition for the while loop and place the return statement outside of the loop

Comment: ah, never mind. you cannot do an assignment as part of a while statement

Comment: "Also, note that your between_brackets regex will not take care of nested brackets:"  - Thank you for pointing that out. I know that these situations will not arrise with the data I am trying to parse. How should I handle these cases if it does matter?

Comment: Regexes are the wrong tool for handling recursive text. You can implement the solution described in the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624) if you need to do that.

Comment: thank you for the link. Is regex right for my situation, or would you recommend a subroutine here too?