# RegEx : How to match 2 pattern and save it to dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I need to make a dictionary list like this (match the owner with their pet type) from log.txt

```
dictionary = {
  "Sophia": "Cat",
  "Julia": "Bird",
  "Max": "Dog"
}
```

log.txt

```
Pet Owner : Sophia
    Colour : Blue
    Pet Type : Cat
    From : India
    Price : High

Pet Owner : Bruce
    Not own pet

Pet Owner : Sean
    Not own pet

Pet Owner : Julia
    Colour : Yellow
    Pet Type : Bird
    From : Israel
    Price : Low

Pet Owner : Bean
    Not own pet

Pet Owner : Max
    Colour : Green
    Pet Type : Dog
    From : Italy
    Price : Normal

Pet Owner : Clarie
    Not own pet
```

What I have try so far

```
import re

log = open("log.txt", "r")
txt = log.read()
log.close()

x = re.search("^Pet.Owner.+", txt)
print(x.group())
```

I stuck at here, I don't know how to make the regEx return 2 keyword that I wanted and save it to the dictionary.txt.

Comment: You can use this `(?:Pet Owner|Pet Type) : ([^\n]+)` pattern and than build object using chunks of two at time from obtained result

Comment: @CodeManiac like this? `x = re.search("(?:Pet Owner|Pet Type) : ([^\n]+)", txt)` ? it give output `Pet Owner : Sophia` what does that mean?

Comment: @IzzuddinJamaluddin you should look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603287/return-multiple-matches-using-re-match-or-re-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tempered greedy token, see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dKAQ1M/1):

```
s = '''Pet Owner : Sophia
    Colour : Blue
    Pet Type : Cat
    From : India
    Price : High

Pet Owner : Bruce
    Not own pet

Pet Owner : Sean
    Not own pet

Pet Owner : Julia
    Colour : Yellow
    Pet Type : Bird
    From : Israel
    Price : Low

Pet Owner : Bean
    Not own pet

Pet Owner : Max
    Colour : Green
    Pet Type : Dog
    From : Italy
    Price : Normal

Pet Owner : Clarie
    Not own pet'''

import re

out = dict( re.findall(r'Pet Owner : (\w+)(?:(?!Pet Owner :).)*Pet Type : (\w+)', s, flags=re.DOTALL) )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Sophia': 'Cat', 'Julia': 'Bird', 'Max': 'Dog'}
```

Comment: what `flags=re.DOTALL` for ?

Comment: @IzzuddinJamaluddin `re.DOTALL` means that `.` character will match newline too. Without it it matches everything but newline. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.DOTALL