# RegEx to delete text in brackets only for specific nested level?

Tags: regex, powershell, nested, brackets

I am currently struggling to find a .NET-RegEx that deletes a given text in brackets only if the brackets are in a nested level of 2.

Here is a sample-string in multiple lines to exlain the problem:

```
(
    (text 
        (bingo)    <-- keep this (level=3)
    text)
    (text)
    (bingo)        <-- kick this (level=2)
    (text)
)
```

Now I need to delete the text "(bingo)" in level 2 but not in any other nested level.

Unfortunately I need to use .NET RegEx for this.
Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: What about the `...(text(bingo)text)...`? Althought the leaf is level 3  the complete parent/child is in fact also level 2. If you would like to exclude this, you should refine your definition with something like: ***... except when it contains any child item***.

Comment: You really need to use a regex for this? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624.

Comment: I agree with @SimonFink you can't use a regex, you need a parser. The simple parser linked to will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem with stateful callbacks that keep track of the nesting level of the parentheses (brackets):

```
$txt = @'
(
    (text 
        (bingo)
    text)
    (text)
    (bingo)
    (text)
)
'@

$level = 1
[regex]::Replace($txt, '\((bingo\))?|\)', { 
    param($m) # the match at hand
    if ($m.Value -eq ')') { # ')' -> decrease level
      ([ref] $level).Value--
      $m.Value
    }
    elseif ($m.Groups[1].Value) { # '(bingo)'
      if (([ref] $level).Value -eq 2) { # remove
        ''
      } else { # keep
        $m.Value
      }
    }
    else { # '(' -> increase level
      ([ref] $level).Value++
      $m.Value
    }
})
```

The above yields:

```
(
    (text 
        (bingo)
    text)
    (text)

    (text)
)
```

Note:

- Only the exact string `(bingo)` is matched.
- Only the matched string itself - if at the requested level - is removed (not the entire line).

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies this is a multi-line string, in which case I would recommend splitting it into an array of strings like so:

```
$StringArray = $StringVar -split “`n”
```

After which point you can iterate through this array and handle each line one at a time, like so:

```
ForEach($String in $StringArray) {
    $Match = [RegEx]::Match($String, "^        \(.*\)")
    if($Match.Success) {
        $KeepStrings += $String
    }
}
```

For composing & undertsanding RegEx strings, I would advise using https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, an expression similar to:

```
^\s{4}\(bingo\).*\s
```

and a replacement of an empty string might be close to work.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pkX61D/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/pkX61D/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: I added the line breaks and spaces in above sample only to make the problem more clear. in the original scenario it is all in one line without any tabs/spaces.