# the syntax for check multiple defrules in clips

Tags: rule-engine, clips, expert-system

I want to check syntax for multiple defrules.
How should I implement this operation?

I know `(check-syntax <construct-or-function-string>)` can check one rule, but it does not support multiple rules in one string.

Example (in clips cli):

```
CLIPS> (check-syntax "(defrule output1 => (printout t \"test for check-syntax 1\") )")
FALSE
CLIPS> (check-syntax "(defrule output1 => (printout t \"test for check-syntax 1\") ) (defrule output2 => (printout t \"test for check-syntax 2\") )")
EXTRANEOUS-INPUT-AFTER-LAST-PARENTHESIS
```

If there is a string containing multiple rules,do I have to split it as a single rule for check-syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The **check-syntax** function will only check a single construct. If you have a string containing multiple rules, you must split that string into multiple strings in order to check each one.

Comment: Is there a recommended split method? Regular matching?

Comment: Alternatively, we can count the open brackets (openBr++) and the stop brackets (openBr--). When openBr is reduced to zero, the string represents a single construct.Like this:[Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624)

Comment: In addition to counting parentheses, for completeness you must also ignore parentheses contained within comments and strings.