# How to ignore repeating regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I was not sure how to phrase the title of this question, but imagine i have the following string:

`(1,2),(3,(4))`

I want a regex that allows me to get `1,2` and `3,(4)`

The regex I currently have is `\\(([^)]*)\\)`.

The problem with this regex is that it gets me `1,2` and `3,(4`. This happens because it is matching the parenthesis of `(4)`. But I need a regex that ignores the 4's parenthesis and only matches the outside ones, if that makes sense.

EDIT: to give more insight on the problem, this is the exact kind of string I expect: `(STRING1,STRING2),(STRING3,STRING4)` where `STRING` is a string of random characters (it can have letters, numbers, whitespaces, other random symbols). Since it has random characters, the strings themselves can have parenthesis, which will trigger the regex. I basically need to keep track of the every parenthesis found that I can ignore close parenthesis that match other open parenthesis.

Comment: You say you need to get `1,2` and `3,(4)` but you also want to ignore the 4's parenthesis?

Comment: Regex is not good at matching arbitrarily nested grammars like that. It will be easier to parse that using your own code, or perhaps a parser library.

Comment: This example is too specific. Please give more examples. Also, could there be other characters in the string that you want to ignore? `(1,2), (3,4)) xyz`. What about white spaces, etc?

Comment: I added more details to my problem. Hopefully it is more clear now. I think @Hulk has gotten the gist of it, but I am not sure how I can implement this.

Comment: @Hulk but I am interested in what is inside. I want exactly what I show in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is probably not the appropriate tool for this job. Instead, an iterative approach can match such things in a single pass, without resorting to recursion etc.

Note: In the meantime, this question has been (correctly) closed as a duplicate.
The following is a somewhat naive and certainly not perfect java implementation of an algorithm very similar to the one proposed in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524624/2513200) linked to from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/2513200) of the linked duplicate.

If you are only interested in the outermost pairs of matching parantheses, something like this may do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                    

    String s = "(1,2),(3,(4))";
    
    ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    
    int depth = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '(') {
            if (depth == 0) {
                startIndex = i;
            }
            depth++;
        }
        if (c == ')') {
            depth--;
            if (depth == 0) {
                matches.add(s.substring(startIndex+1, i));
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(matches.size());
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Note that this code does not handle cases where the input contains more closing than opening parantheses - the `depth` just gets negative. You may want to add sytax-error handling for these cases (and I'm sure there are others).

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!